# how can I save data from a form in mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've to store data from input form in Angular.js and store data in mongoDB with MongoClient. Can you suggest me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Using AngularJS with MongoDB](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2301560)

A TL;DR:

1) Create a DB reference `var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);`

2) Take data from form and insert it to the db: `db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert({field1: data_from_form1, field2: data_from_form2, field3: data_from_form3})`